# How to check if a variable is defined in a Jenkins folder?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a Jenkins folder which has multiple jobs in it. I've also defined some variables in the folder itself. How can I check if the folder has a variable defined? I tied

```
import jenkins.model.*

private def getBuildJob(final String folder) {
  def jobFolder = null
  for (f in Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractItem.class)) {
    if (f.fullName == folder) {
      jobFolder = f
      break
    }
  }
  return jobFolder
}

node("linux-ubuntu") {
    stage("test") {
        def folder = getBuildJob("MyFolderName")
        println folder.hasVariable("MY_VARIABLE")
    }
}
```

But I get

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder.hasVariable() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [MY_VARIABLE]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
```

Comment: How did you create Folder Specific variables? Did you use https://plugins.jenkins.io/folder-properties/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the folder-properties plugin you can use the following script.

```
@NonCPS
def checkVar() {
  def folderName = "Folderycr" 
  def propToCheck = "YCRPROP"
  def folderItem = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.AbstractFolder.class).find{ (it.name == folderName) }

  println folderItem.getProperties().each { prop ->
    if(prop instanceof com.mig82.folders.properties.FolderProperties){
      prop.getProperties().each{
        if(it.key == propToCheck) {
          println "Prop is available. Vale is : " + it.value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

node("linux-node") {
  stage("Run test") {
    checkVar()
  }
}
```

Comment: when I enclose the code in `node("linux-node") {}`, I get an exception `Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder`

Comment: I just need to use `@NonCPS`